# How can I display a simple notification in android?

Tags: java, android

How can I display a simple notification in notification bar in Android? Please help me with the easiest solution.

Comment: Yes I did. But they all seems little bit confusing.All I want is a simple method.

Comment: [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) or [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) ?

Comment: @Andromise Post the codes which you have read and tell us where are you getting confused and people answering this question I am not understanding without any research efforts shown by him how can you directly provide the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you are asking about notification in notificationbar.If its so,Try this code,

```
private void showNotification(String eventtext, Context ctx) {



    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.noti_icon,
            text, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
    // notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
            new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, "Title", eventtext,
            contentIntent);

    // Send the notification.
    mNotificationManager.notify("Title", 0, notification);
}
```

Comment: @WHK: its Notification Manager

Answer (score 9):

It's easy. In this example a notification is fired when the button is clicked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#A9BCF5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Create Notification" >
    <Button>

<LinearLayout> 


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              //We get a reference to the NotificationManager
              NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

              String MyText = "Reminder";
              Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
              //The three parameters are: 1. an icon, 2. a title, 3. time when the notification appears

              String MyNotificationTitle = "Medicine!";
              String MyNotificationText  = "Don't forget to take your medicine!";

              Intent MyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
              //A PendingIntent will be fired when the notification is clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent

              mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);

              int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
              notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , mNotification);  
              //We are passing the notification to the NotificationManager with a unique id.
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You can add a sound or vibration to the notification as well. For more information, you can see [this](http://www.b2creativedesigns.com/notification.php) tutorial.

Comment: Though the Notification constructor mentioned has been deprecated...still +1...Notification.Builder() is the new way to create Notification.